# How can I select only columns with a YouTube video link?

Tags: regex

I have a column in my MySQL database simply titled "Post", which is a TEXT type. I want to select any Post field that contains a YouTube video link.

I'm pretty sure the answer will have to do with regex. In my PHP script, I embed YouTube videos of the post by getting the video ID via regex in PHP, but the same regex does not work for a MySQL select query.

I looked into MySQL regex and it seems far too simple to be able to do this... but I'm probably totally wrong and missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls add some sample data.

Comment: Sample data (pretend these are all in the same column in a table):

Hi | What's up | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4FItFf96oY | https://stackoverflow.com/ | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSKLnOyaP7A

From the data above, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4FItFf96oY" and "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSKLnOyaP7A" should be selected from the database.

Comment: Please add the REGEX attempt that was used that is not giving the expected results.

Comment: Also ... put the sample data, your attempted solution, etc ... into the Question.  Use the EDIT button.

Comment: You are correct that MySQL regexes don't support many advanced regex features (e.g. lookahead / lookbehind, back references)  But that doesn't necessarily mean they are insufficient for your problem.

Comment: Isn't a LIKE search what you are looking for?
select * from PostTable Where Post LIKE '%youtube.com%';

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.